# Is it safe to use count property to get bool value returned, with statements like if([[uiTableView selectedRowIndexes] count]) 

Tags: objective-c, count, unsafe

Maybe this is a little tricky ....

Someone said that:

The count (of an NSTableView selectedRowIndexes for example) could easily be neither YES nor NO; for another, if the user selected a multiple of 256 items, the lowest byte of the count would be 0, so the BOOL value would be NO even though there is a selection.

Is it true?

So, if it is it's unsafe to use a statement like `if([[uiTableView selectedRowIndexes] count]) {...}` and we should use `if([[uiTableView selectedRowIndexes] count] > 0) {...}`.

Right ?
Any comments ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite.

In C, for the purposes of `if` statements, any nonzero-valued expression evaluates as true.

In Objective-C, the `BOOL` type is a `char`. So in any situation where you're casting an integer value to `BOOL`, explicitly or implicitly, only the lower 8 bits are retained, and thus multiples of 256 will be interpreted as `NO`. An easy way to run into this problem is to return an integer in a `BOOL`-valued function:

```
- (BOOL)arrayIsNotEmpty:(NSArray *)array
{
    // WRONG - will return NO if array contains a multiple of 256 items
    return [array count];

    // RIGHT
    return ([array count] > 0);
}
```

However, uses of the form

```
if ([array count])
    // ...
```

which evaluate integers as truth values without casting to `BOOL` are fine.

Comment: So if we use a form if([array count] && isChecked) ?? I think that this is casting to BOOL, so is wrong right ? -isChecked is BOOL of course-

Comment: OR in this case ... if we use if(![array count])... ??

Comment: No, that shouldn't cast to BOOL. Even in the case of arithmetic with BOOL, C will promote shorter integer types rather than demote longer ones. I believe you're safe unless you explicitly cast to BOOL or pass an integer through a BOOL parameter or return value.